# Output showing Undefined using find array helper in javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

So, here is the code which is using find helper in javaScript and supposed to return a value but instead of that it is showing undefined.

```
function Car(model) {
this.model = model;
}
var cars = {
 new Car('Buick'),
 new Car('Camaro'),
 new Car('Focus')
};
cars.find(function(car){
 return car.model === 'Focus';
});
```

I am running this code in VB and the output supposed to be Focus but it is showing undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cars variable needs to be an array not an object as you don't have keys, just a list.
Here is a working example:

```js
function Car(model) {
  this.model = model;
}
var cars = [
  new Car('Buick'),
  new Car('Camaro'),
  new Car('Focus')
];
console.log(cars.find((car) => car.model === 'Focus'));
```